# RGB integer to Color object

Tags: java, colors, awt, awtrobot

I am drawing an integer from a Color using this code:

```
robot.getPixelColor(x, y).getRGB()
```

Now how do I go from an integer back to an RGB color? I've looked about and I havn't seen anything that does this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `getPixelColor(x,y)` returns a `java.awt.Color`.

```
Color color = robot.getPixelColor(x,y);
int rgb = color.getRGB();
Color color2 = new Color(rgb);
```

Comment: +1 Don't forget to include `true` or `false` to indicate if the ALPHA value should extract from the packed `int` as well